# Update en SQLAlchemy recorriendo los campos de la tabla

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Necesito recorrer los campos de una tabla para reemplazar los vacíos por nulos. Lo intenté de la siguiente manera pero me da error.

```
campossql=['prueba1', 'prueba2', 'fecha']

for i in campossql:

connection.execute(update(table).where(table.c.i == '' ).values(prueba1 = None))
```

> ```
> raise exception AttributeError: i
> ```

Cabe mensionar que la tabla contiene los campos 'prueba1', 'prueba2' y 'fecha'.

Gracias, agradezco cualquier ayuda así sea de otra manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta, sería:

```py
campossql=['prueba1', 'prueba2', 'fecha']

for i in campossql:
    connection.execute(update(table).where(table.c[i] == '' ).values({i : None}))
```